# como eu adiciono numeros na lista usando o for?

Tags: python

1.nesta saída só adiciona o número 10.Como eu adiciono os 10 numeros na sequencia?

```
lista = []
for i in range(1, 11)
lista = i
```

Comment: Não precisa do `for` faça apenas `lista.extend(range(1, 11))`. Veja o exemplo https://ideone.com/aqrhzp

Comment: Ou simplesmente `lista = list(range(1, 11))` :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se você quiser utilizar o for para adicionar números na lista, lembre-se que o for em python deve terminar com dois pontos (:).
Já para adicionar elementos na lista, você pode utilizar o .append() logo após o nome da sua lista.
O código ficaria tipo:

```
lista = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    lista.append(i)
```

Comment: Eu precisava criar uma função para não usar o append... achei que com o loop for iria dar certo, mas ele não adiciona sequencia, só substitui

Comment: Oi, Gabriel. Tudo bem? Se você não quiser usar o append, tente alterar a última linha (lista.append(i)) por: lista = lista + [i]